# how to use python to run a google search and print out the results

Tags: python, web

I wonder if you can help. I want to write a script in python that will run a query on google and output the results of the query as

Thanks

adaptive

Comment: Yes, we can help. But a little more concrete, what part are you having problems with? Parsing the results? Fetching the html?

Comment: I was looking for both the ways to do it and the ways to parse the results. I am new to this and I want guidance in the direction I should be looking. There seems to be different ways but I want to know which ways are best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
>>> import twill.commands
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> class browser:
...    def __init__(self, url="http://www.google.com",log = None):
...       self.a=twill.commands
...       self.a.config("readonly_controls_writeable", 1)
...       self.b = self.a.get_browser()
...       self.b.set_agent_string("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14")
...       self.log = log
...       self.b.clear_cookies()
...       self.url=url
...    def googleQuery(self, query="python code"):
...       self.b.go(self.url)
...       #self.b.showforms()
...       f = self.b.get_form("f")
...       #print "form is %s" % f
...       f["q"] = query
...       self.b.clicked(f, "btnG")
...       self.b.submit()
...       pageContent = self.b.get_html()
...       soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(pageContent)
...       ths = soup.findAll(attrs={"class" : "l"})
...       for a in ths:
...          print a
... 
>>> t=browser()
>>> t.googleQuery("twill queries")
==> at http://www.google.ie/
Note: submit is using submit button: name="btnG", value="Google Search"

<a href="http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/WhosUsingPyparsing" class="l" onmousedown="return clk    (this.href,'','','res','1','','0CBMQFjAA')">pyparsing - WhosUsingPyparsing</a>
<a href="http://www.mail-archive.com/twill@lists.idyll.org/msg00048.html" class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','res','2','','0CBcQFjAB')">Re: [<em>twill</em>] <em>query</em>: docs, and web site.</a>
<a href="http://www.mail-archive.com/twill@lists.idyll.org/msg00050.html" class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','res','3','','0CBkQFjAC')">Re: [<em>twill</em>] <em>query</em>: docs, and web site.</a>
<a href="http://www.genealogytoday.com/surname/finder.mv?Surname=Twill" class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','res','4','','0CB4QFjAD')"><em>Twill</em> Genealogy and Family Tree Resources - Surname Finder</a>
<a href="http://a706cheap-apparel.hobby-site.com/ladies-cotton-faded-twill-le-chameau-breeks-42" class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','res','5','','0CCEQFjAE')">Ladies Cotton Faded <em>Twill</em> Le Chameau Breeks 42</a>
<a href="http://twill.idyll.org/examples.html" class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','res','6','','0CCMQFjAF')"><em>twill</em> Examples</a>
<a href="http://panjiva.com/Sri-Lankan-Manufacturers-Of/twill+capri" class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','res','7','','0CCcQFjAG')">Sri-Lankan <em>Twill</em> Capri Manufacturers | Sri-Lankan Suppliers of <b>...</b></a>
<a href="http://c586cheap-apparel.dyndns.ws/twill-beige-blazer" class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','res','8','','0CCoQFjAH')"><em>Twill</em> beige blazer</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267537/how-do-you-use-relative-paths-for-twill-tests" class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','res','9','','0CCwQFjAI')">How do you use Relative Paths for <em>Twill</em> tests? - Stack Overflow</a>
<a href="http://mytextilenotes.blogspot.com/2010/01/introduction-to-twill-weave.html" class="l" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','res','10','','0CC8QFjAJ')">My Textile Notes: Introduction to <em>Twill</em> Weave</a>
```

> > > 

Comment: Is BeautifulSoup for parsing the html then? Will it parse xml too?

Comment: there is BeautifulStoneSoup for xml parsing. Documentation for BeautifulStoneSoup can be found at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML

Answer (score 2):

This [example](http://dcortesi.com/2008/05/28/google-ajax-search-api-example-python-code/) should help you.

Comment: When I first clicked on that link I got to your page with the solution to my problem but the link doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: @adaptive: Strange, the link is working for me. Try the Google cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:eI3Cv08R1SAJ:dcortesi.com/2008/05/28/google-ajax-search-api-example-python-code/+http://dcortesi.com/2008/05/28/google-ajax-search-api-example-python-code/&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk